# How can I stop zsh from autocorrecting on proper commands?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm having a very strange issue with an install of zsh on my local machine. It attempts to correct commands I've typed very aggressively.

Here are two examples.

If I type `which ssh` it will ask me if I meant `.ssh`. I also experience this with command names, not just arguments. If I type `autotest`, it will ask if I meant `.autotest`. I have two other machines with zsh installed and this does not happen.

I've attempted to completely remove all zsh config files from my home directory and regenerate them. I've also tried `hash -rf` with no luck.

I'm tempted to just turn off the correct feature, but I'd like to continue using it if I can and just find a way to get it to behave. It can be very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix would be to disable correction for commands likely to take other command-names.

```
alias which='nocorrect which'
```